# save a string with html as image

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I have a string with whole html from web page.
I want to save this string as image with all html rules.
At the end to have image from webpage. How can I solve it with c# and asp.net?

Comment: Are you saying you want to render the string as HTML to an image file so that you finish with a 'picture' of the web page as a browser would show it?

Comment: you want to render the html as a full page and then have a screenshot/image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert a HTML file to a PDF by using the following component:

http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/

Then use ghostscript to convert the PDF to an image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this project as a source of inspiration for your code.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/IECapture.aspx

Of course, this is a regular Winform-application

Or this component:

http://www.acasystems.com/en/web-thumb-activex/faq-convert-html-to-image-in-asp.net.htm