# I need a function or something to change internet explorer settings before printing

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to change Internet explorer printing settings before printing?

I want the following options enabled by the function in the background and only the printer dialog showing up for the user to click 'print'

if its not possible, are there any alternatives?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't be done.

Can you imagine the havoc you could wreak if you could change a browser's settings from JavaScript? Don't forget this is where all the security and privacy settings reside as well.

Comment: All I can suggest it to put up instructions to the user. Not very helpful, though.

Comment: Take a look here as well:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898250/save-a-string-with-html-as-image

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible.

You can generate a PDF. There you have more control over how the printout looks.

Comment: Which language are you using serverside? You can use http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/ for example (PHP5).